# MPEG Transport Stream Audio data information

Tags: audio, aac, mpeg2-ts

I am writing a code to extract AAC audio data from mpeg ts stream. I want to get stream properties like sampling frequency, number of channels, Audio type, Audio profile type etc. from Transport stream, without decoding the actual data. How much of the information will be available from stream?

Also I want to know is there any way to find the total duration of the stream without actually finding the last PTS value in the file

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AAC frames packed in TS use ADTS headers. Its 7 (or 9) bytes, and very easy to parse. ADTS header format is documented well online.

Comment: what about duration of the stream?

Comment: Transport streams don't have a duration encoded. You must read the first and last timestamp and divide by 90000.

Comment: 16 bits in PES header.. that means it can be upto 64Kb for audio right?

Comment: and is there any way to seek the .ts file?

Comment: New questions belong in new posts. Comments are not discussions.